# Laravel rate limiting API authenticated with API Token

Tags: php, laravel, restful-authentication, rate-limiting, throttling

I am building a restful API for users of my Laravel application to retrieve their data.

The current plan is that they can generate an API Token within the application to then authenticate their API requests. I do not know from where they will be making the requests.

The main reason I want to implement rate limiting is to reduce the impact of accidental/intentional DDOS, as well as part of the users current subscription package (necessary). Because of the latter, different users may have different rates.

Laravel already provides a rate limiter built in, including access to dynamic user limits specified in the User table.

I'm wondering though how the session is handled. From what I can see the Laravel TokenGuard class does not store the the user between requests. Therefore the user is being retrieved between every request, even to retrieve the rate limit. This seems to defeat the point of the rate limiter if we are still making database queries each time.

What is the appropriate way to handle this?

If I write my own authentication middleware, and store the user in the session, would that work? Do requests sent from another server (not a browser) even handle sessions?

Thanks.

Comment: Laravel rateLimit  dont attention what users request to application if the number of requests became more than limit amount all users denied to access any route that has Api in its prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time anyone accesses your site, you are spinning up an entire Laravel instance which is already putting stress on your server. DDOS doesn't depend on distressing your DB only. If someone is determined to DDOS you, you are going to notice! All you can do is mitigate the problem, so don't worry too much that each request has an associated DB call.

You could have a local session, but in the long run this is a bad design decision, since it introduces state to your server, which will make scaling in the future much harder. (https://12factor.net/ for more info on that.) This is why Laravel uses the user stored in the DB instead.

Unless you are doing something pretty special, it's generally safe to assume that Laravel is using an adequate solution. They do frameworks so that you can worry about business logic!

Finally, there are many websites out there. The chances are that by the time you're big enough to attract attention of people trying to DDOS you (remember it takes resources, and, therefore, money) you'll probably be using a much more sophisticated system.

Answer (score 0):

If a request with some kind of token reaches your application, you should not need any kind of session. As you've assumed: a session is usually handled through cookies, but raw HTTP calls (like cURL does it) usually don't use them.

Don't overestimate the cost of getting the current user from the database - if your application performs some more actions, these additional actions will make the difference! Getting one entity from the database is fairly cheap, compared to everything else, and to check for the proper permissions and rate limits, this is obviously neccessary.

Everything else looks like you're looking for something like Laravel Passport (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport). Additional tools like the Throttle package (see https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Throttle) will help you to enable the rate limiting for your routes